# Block Desendants while selecting child elements

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a drop down list by using `nested Un ordered lists.`

My case is i have an `unordered list`, which is having another `unordered list` inside of its `li` element. I had written hover for the `first level li` elements by using the `child selector`. My problem is while hovering the `first level li` element, the css for its hovering process is also get applied to its `child li` element. My question is why does the child selector selecting its descendants in my case..? and what should i do to avoid this in future.?

### [DEMO - Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dVXJg/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution below:

> **My question is why does the child selector selecting its descendants in my case..?**

Because you have defined one part of the CSS by adding `#ULHeaderMenuWrapperMenuCollection > li:hover`

> **what should i do to avoid this in future.?**

You have to protect the inheritance by adding `#ULHeaderMenuWrapperMenuCollection > li:hover div ul li` to your CSS. Here is the [Working Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/dVXJg/3/).

```
#ULHeaderMenuWrapperMenuCollection > li:hover div ul li
{
color:black;
}

#ULHeaderMenuWrapperMenuCollection > li:hover div ul li:hover
{
color:orange;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

*Updated to fit to your original code*

When you mouse is hover your sublist, it's still hover the main one.

I suggest you to put your `<li>` text in a `<span>` or a `<a>`, which makes your css simplest :

**HTML**

```
<ul id="ULHeaderMenuWrapperMenuCollection">
    <li>        
        <span>Products</span>                  
        <div id="DivProductsMenu">
            <div id="DivProductsMenuUpper">
                <ul> 
                    <li><span>CIMS</span></li>
                    <li><span>VPRO</span></li>
                    <li><span>BIRIS</span></li> 
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="DivProductsMenuLower">
                <ul> 
                    <li><span>PATRON</span></li>
                    <li><span>DEAL</span></li>
                    <li><span>MEDIX</span></li> 
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </li>                              
    <li>
        <span>Contact Us</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#ULHeaderMenuWrapperMenuCollection li > span:hover {
    color:orange;
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dVXJg/4/)